# Input value in type number lost when display block -> none -> block - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little bit confused. I have lots of input of type=number and I did a script to sum the values of each input selected. In fact, all is working fine, except one thing.

If for example I am setting the value of any input to any number (except the default value), then I am unselecting this input (it goes on display: none which is then not added to my sum). When I am selecting it back, its value come back to the default one (which is 1), but .val() gives me the previous value before I unselected it so my sum dont add the correct value. Also, the input not seems to work after that.

I tried putting it on visibility hidden -> visible after but not seems to work... It lose his previous value when I change the display or visibility...

I am not sure if I am clear, but here's the code:

```
$('.choices').click(function (evt) {
    // Add Quantity Selector
    var id = $(this).children('.option_name').attr('id');
    id = id.replace('name_', '');
    if ($(this).children('.option_price_raw').text() != '0' && !($(this).hasClass('epoxy-kit'))) {
        $(this).append('<div id="quantity_' + id + '" class="option_quantity" style="visibility: visible;">Quantity:<input class="qty_option" name="qty_option" min="1" type="number" value="1"/></div>');
    }

    $('.option_quantity').each(function () { $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden') });

    // Display quantity selector on selected
    $('.choices:not(.selected) .option_quantity').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.choices:contains([id*="152615"]) .option_quantity').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    if ($(this).children('.option_price_raw').text() != "0" && !($(this).is('[id*="152615"]'))) {
        $('.selected .option_quantity').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    // Detect how many flakes selected
    var maximum_flakes = 8;
    var count_flakes = 0;
    var flakes_to_add = 0;

    $('.epoxy-flakes, .option_quantity').on('click change', function (evt) {
        count_flakes = 0;
        $('.epoxy-flakes.selected').each(function () {
            flakes_to_add = +($(this).children('.option_quantity').children('input').val());
            count_flakes += flakes_to_add;
        });

        if (count_flakes >= maximum_flakes) {
            $('.epoxy-flakes:not(.selected)').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            $('.max_error_msg').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else {
            $('.epoxy-flakes:not(.selected)').css('pointer-events', 'all');
            $('.max_error_msg').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });

    // Stop propagation on quantity selector
    $('.option_quantity').on('click change', function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        update_price();
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you provide a reproducing fiddle?

Comment: It is difficult to assist in cases like this without a [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.